# Java how to read a variable which is passed to args[0] from other public class methods

Tags: java, oop, command-line-interface, args

I am trying to read arguments passed to a jar file but my doubt is - If there is any way that we can read the constructor of parent class variables directly from subclass for example

KafkaSparkStreaming is my parent class and my hbaseconnection is my subclass now my doubt is how to get hostname from parent class passed as arguments to my child class Hbaseconnection also I don't want to set this as a parameter maybe whole understanding pass by reference and value might be wrong.

## PARENT CLASS

```
public class KafkaSparkStreaming {

  public String hostDetails;
  public String zipCodePath;

  public KafkaSparkStreaming(String[] args){
    this.hostDetails = args[0];
    this.zipCodePath = args[1];
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if(args.length<2) {
        System.out.println("Arguments must be supplied ");
        System.out.println("Usage: args[0] --> hostName args[1] --> path of zipcodecsv file");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    KafkaSparkStreaming cdhHost = new KafkaSparkStreaming(args);
  }
}
```

## CHILD CLASS

```
 public class HbaseConnection extends KafkaSparkStreaming implements 
 Serializable  {
    public static String host;
    public HbaseConnection(String[] args) {
    super(args);
}

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Admin hbaseAdmin = null;
    public static Admin getHbaseAdmin() throws IOException {
    org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration conf = 
(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration) HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.setInt("timeout", 12000000);
    conf.set("hbase.master","cloudera-instance:60000");            
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "cloudera-instance");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
    conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase");
    Connection con = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);

    try {

    if (hbaseAdmin == null)
    //hbaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
    hbaseAdmin = con.getAdmin();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
return hbaseAdmin;

 }
```

Comment: You do not use `host` in `HbaseConnection` class

Answer (score 1):

Since `hostDetails` is a `public` property in `KafkaSparkStreaming` and `HbaseConnection` extends `KafkaSparkStreaming` objects of type `HbaseConnection` have access to that property from parent class. You can use it directly in `HbaseConnection`.

Comment: the way i have used constructors to pass args does it look fine? because still the values doesnt get populated there and i get exception job aborted.

Answer (score 1):

Since `HbaseConnection` is a sub-class of `KafkaSparkStreaming`, you can simply access it using its name as shown below -

```
public class HbaseConnection extends KafkaSparkStreaming {

    // rest of your code

    public void getDetails() {
        // do something here    
        System.out.println("Host details from sub-class" + hostDetails);
    }

}
```

Comment: when i add the method public void getDetails i get exception and it asks to create            
       public HbaseConnection(String[] args) {
        super(args);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       } i am not sure if this correct

Comment: @vinodh And what is the exception?? That is correct, but don't create a constructor that just take a random String array... Acually start with `public KafkaSparkStreaming(String host, String zipCode)`

Comment: ok Nicholas i will try this. Exception was regarding constructor not explicitly defined in child class.